# Qliksense Date Comparison Error

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to check if one date is greater than another. This is the formula I'm using:

```
=if(
Date(PYMT_DT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') >=  Date($(Var_StartDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
AND
Date(PYMT_DT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= Date($(Var_EndDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
,1,0)
```

PYMT_DT is a field from my query. Var_StartDate and Var_EndDate are variables.

The formula always returns 0. However, it works correctly if I type a date directly into the formula.

Let's use these values for an example:

```
PYMT_DT = 10/21/2016
Var_StartDate = 10/20/2016
Var_EndDate = 10/30/2016
```

That should give me a 1, but I get a 0 instead. However, if I replace PYMT_DT with the actual date value I get the correct result:

```
=if(
Date('10/21/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy') >=  Date($(Var_StartDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
AND
Date('10/21/2016', 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= Date($(Var_EndDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
,1,0)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this looks like your PYMT_DT is not being recognised as a date when it's being loaded in - maybe try using date#

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think that's definitely the problem. Unfortunately Qlik still isn't recognizing the field as a date when I use date#.

Comment: I've come across this before, the only way to resolve it is to take a long hard look at your date format coming in and try to cater for it. You can try `date(date#(PYMT_DT, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM dd yyyy')` in a table next to a dimension of PYMT_DT - non-converted values will show you where it's not working

Answer (score 0):

First point is the format, it need to be uppercase `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. The second point is that you need `Date#` function to convert text to date (`Date` only changes the format of a date or a number). The Third point is that your variable needs to be wrapped with `'$(variable)'` be be interpreted the value of the variable as a value, not as as variable.

For the variables, would recommend creating already as a date using `MakeDate`.

The code below you can paste and run

```
LET Var_StartDate = MakeDate(2016, 10, 20);
LET Var_EndDate = MakeDate(2016, 10, 30);

DATA:
LOAD 
    PYMT_DT,
    if(Date#(PYMT_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >=  '$(Var_StartDate)' AND Date#(PYMT_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '$(Var_EndDate)', 1, 0) as test
Inline [
    PYMT_DT
    10/19/2016
    10/21/2016
    11/01/2016];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there's a chance your dates have a time component, you also need to make sure you `floor()` them for comparison otherwise it could be the time that's the issue. As well as using the right formatting etc this might lead to:

```
=if(
floor(Date#(PYMT_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) >= floor(Date#('$(Var_StartDate)', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
AND
floor(Date#(PYMT_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) <= floor(Date#('$(Var_EndDate)', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
,1,0)
```